# How to manually generate nginx http cache file?

Tags: php, nginx

I want to generate nginx http cache files directly from PHP. File structure is below:

```
{bytecode}
KEY: {cache_key}
{bytecode}{http_headers}

{body}
```

So question is how to generate {bytecode} placeholders?

Comment: Hi 2 years later any news about it? do you have any problem doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You *SHOULD NOT* manually create any cache files inside nginx's cache. It will lead to hardly-detected problems.

Only removing files from cache directory is about right - except you are using ["open_file_cache"](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#open_file_cache) directive (in this case you'll observe caching errors till "inactive" time expires).

If you still need to make cache files manually - it means that you business logic is wrong. Please redesign it without manual intervention into nginx's internals.

Comment: Could you explain EXACTLY why is that bad idea, because for now I successfully updating these cache files by replacing {body} placeholder (look at my example structure) with the new content and nginx works perfectly?